# Write text in middle of the image before hover

Tags: css

I have an image with gray filter in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joLqvqyd/2/), as you can see in hover action I remove filter, I want to know how can I add a simple text just in middle in image when filter is active, then remove in hover just like filter.. Something like "Hover image to see our offices", it can be with css? or we need js for that?

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

area {
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.profile-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
  box-shadow: #222 0.2em 0.2em 1em;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(135%) contrast(120%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(135%) contrast(120%);
  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.profile-pic:hover,
.profile-pic:focus {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  box-shadow: #224 0.2em 0.2em 0.6em 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img id="mapImage" src="https://i.imgur.com/Y7HuHDQ.png" usemap="#image-map" class="profile-pic">

  <map name="image-map">
    
<area target="" data-text="USA Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173" alt="USA" title="USA" href="" coords="110,140,182,141,186,148,198,146,198,140,214,139,224,134,234,143,221,150,213,154,205,156,205,170,199,174,194,181,193,188,162,182,158,171,149,173,145,179,141,170,124,168,121,173,112,168,105,158" shape="poly">
                
<area target="" data-text="Mexico Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="MEXICO" title="MEXICO" href="" coords="124,172,137,171,141,178,152,173,160,181,162,204,179,199,179,211,157,212,173,216,146,204,136,196,125,188" shape="poly">
                 
<area target="" data-text="Japan Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="JAPAN" title="JAPAN" href="" coords="705,106,716,106,721,146,687,184,667,175" shape="poly">
                 
<area target="" data-text="Germany Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="GERMANY" title="GERMANY" href="" coords="418,111,436,108,433,124,418,124" shape="poly">
<div class="tooltip" id="tooltip"></div>   
</map>

</div>
```

Comment: DO you want text that works as a `title="some text"` or something more complex? Also specify which element is hovered in order to display the text, hope that makes sense

Comment: ya I want to put some text in middle of image it can be like a  `<div class="title"><h1>TEXT HERE</h1></div>` also `.profile-pic` class add filter to image and `.profile-pic:hover` remove that filter on hover, si I want to put that text before hover and do same effect of filter (dismiss filter) with text in hover action  @AntonyMN

Answer (score 1):

If you change your CSS to this it'll get rid of the label when you hover over the map.

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  transition: .2s all;
  opacity: 1;
}

area {
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.profile-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
  box-shadow: #222 0.2em 0.2em 1em;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(135%) contrast(120%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(135%) contrast(120%);
  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.profile-pic:hover,
.profile-pic:focus {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  box-shadow: #224 0.2em 0.2em 0.6em 0.1em;
}

.profile-pic:hover ~ map > .tooltip,
.profile-pic:focus ~ map > .tooltip{
opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Where I should put text in html?

Comment: With my changes I would put it inside of the `.tooltip` div

Comment: but if I want text over image, I mean in center, there is a fiddle if I put into tooltip div https://jsfiddle.net/joLqvqyd/3/

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
$(".profile-pic").mouseover(function(){
    $("p").hide();
});

$(".profile-pic").mouseout(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  top:20%;
  left:40%;
}

area {
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.profile-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
  box-shadow: #222 0.2em 0.2em 1em;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(135%) contrast(120%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(135%) contrast(120%);
  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.profile-pic:hover,
.profile-pic:focus {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  box-shadow: #224 0.2em 0.2em 0.6em 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<p class="tooltip">Hello</p>
  <img id="mapImage" src="https://i.imgur.com/Y7HuHDQ.png" usemap="#image-map" class="profile-pic">

  <map name="image-map">

            <area target="" data-text="USA Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173" alt="USA" title="USA" href="" coords="110,140,182,141,186,148,198,146,198,140,214,139,224,134,234,143,221,150,213,154,205,156,205,170,199,174,194,181,193,188,162,182,158,171,149,173,145,179,141,170,124,168,121,173,112,168,105,158" shape="poly">

             <area target="" data-text="Mexico Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="MEXICO" title="MEXICO" href="" coords="124,172,137,171,141,178,152,173,160,181,162,204,179,199,179,211,157,212,173,216,146,204,136,196,125,188" shape="poly">

             <area target="" data-text="Japan Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="JAPAN" title="JAPAN" href="" coords="705,106,716,106,721,146,687,184,667,175" shape="poly">

             <area target="" data-text="Germany Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="GERMANY" title="GERMANY" href="" coords="418,111,436,108,433,124,418,124" shape="poly">
          <!--<div class="tooltip" id="tooltip"></div>-->   
    </map>

</div>
```

Comment: I highly discourage people to not use JS/ jQuery when creating a hover event like this. This should be done in CSS

Comment: I used jQuery because I have to hide the `p` on hovering on the `.profile-pic` and I can't nest the `p` in the `.profile-pic:hover` selector

Comment: @connoraworden what better way do you suggest?

Comment: I've answered it now https://stackoverflow.com/a/50610009/5122821 use a sibling (`~`) and child (`>`) selector